# Binary column entry converted to .pdf file in RAILS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, binary, attachment

How can I retrieve my PDF binary data from a rails db entry and output it into a PDF format? This is what I've got so far, but this is just displaying and empty PDF file:

```
def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    # Create .pdf from binaries
    @submissions.each do |sub|
      @filePath = Rails.root.join('tmp/system/', sub.id.to_s, sub.file_file_name)
        logger.error('Filepath here: ' + @filePath.to_s)
        @content = Attachment.find_by! submission_id: 174
        File.open(@filePath.to_s, 'w:binary') do |out|
          out.write(@content.file_contents)
      end
    end
```

Why is this not writting anything into the PDF document?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need more information about what you're doing. Show us the minimal code you've written toward solving this. If you haven't written any then http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 would be applicable. Besides binary data, what is in `file_content`? A PDF file?

Comment: I think the question is quite explicit. You don't need more information for this kind of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here:

```
# Download zip file of all submission
  def download
    @submissions = Submission.all

    # Create .pdf from binaries
    @submissions.each do |sub|
      @filePath = Rails.root.join('tmp/system/', sub.id.to_s)
      Dir.mkdir(@filePath.to_s)
        @content = Attachment.find_by! submission_id: sub.id
        File.open((@filePath.to_s + '/' + sub.file_file_name.to_s), 'w+b') do |out|
          out.write(@content.file_contents)
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can just write it out:

```
File.open('/tmp/whatever.pdf', 'w:binary') do |out|
  out.write(model.file_content)
end
```

Keep in mind if you need a truly temporary file, use [Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html):

```
file = Tempfile.new
file.write(model.file_content)
file.close
```

To use this file:

```
do_something_with_pdf(file.path)
```

When finished, remove it:

```
file.unlink
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @tadman. Really appreciate it. Unfortunately I cannot try this until Monday, but I will post my reply here. Hopefully your suggestion will work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see my updated question above. This is not decoding the pdf properly, unfortunately, my pdf cannot open after, even though the coding/decoding seems ok